# Custom select and option elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

A picture of what I'm trying to make:

[image]

I want to make a custom select + option drop down menu. Is there a way of including content within the option tags, or am I better off making a drop down menu with jQuery and  elements:

```
<div class="dropDown">
<ul>
    <li>Option 1 html here</li>
    <li>Option 2 html here</li>
    <li>Option 3 html here</li>
    <li>Option 4 html here</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: give me that link, please..

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/DyePoBm.jpg is just a photoshop job I did. Sorry if that was confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you want, this is simple example code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropDown').click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
  });
  $('li').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).find('h1').text();
    $('#click').text(text);
  });
});
```

```css
li{
  cursor:pointer;  
  background:#000;
  display:block;
  }
li div{
  background-image:url('http://netweaver.com.au/floatHouse/pics/red.gif');
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  }
li h1{
  background:#333;
  color:#eee;
  font-size:12px;
  }
li p{
  background:#666;
  color:#222;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropDown"><div id='click'>Click Me</div>
<ul>
    <li><div></div><h1>Title 1</h1><p>Option 1 html here</p></li>
    <li><div></div><h1>Title 2</h1><p>Option 2 html here</p></li>
    <li><div></div><h1>Title 3</h1><p>Option 3 html here</p></li>
    <li><div></div><h1>Title 4</h1><p>Option 4 html here</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was planning on doing. I just wanted to make sure that it wasn't best practice to modify the <option> tags.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with pure css assuming your content within the drop-down menu is remaining the same.